# Controlling trimming behavior of DirectShow's AVIMux?

Tags: directshow, avi

When the directshow AVIMux is provided with two streams of data (e.g. audio and video) and one stream starts a bit before the other, is there any way to control how the AVIMux behaves? Namely, if the AVIMux gets a few video frames before the audio starts, it will actually omit the video frames from the output AVI. This contrasts with what it does when audio is missing at the end, when it includes the video frames anyways.

My sources for the audio and video are live streams (commercial capture filters I can't really improve/control), and I'd like to keep the video frames even though the audio starts a bit later.

Is there a nice way to do this? I can imagine wrapping the two filters into a custom filter with its own graph and inserting silence as necessary, but it would be awesome to not have to go to all of that trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The question has seemingly incorrect assumption about dropping frames in the multiplexer. The multiplexer looks at video and audio data time stamps. If "a few frames before..." means that time stamps are negative and the data is preroll data, then it's dropped and excluded from resulting file. Otherwise it's included regardless of the actual order of data on the input of the multiplexer. Respective audio silence will be present in the beginning of the audio track.

That is, make sure the data is correctly time stamped and multiplexer will get it written.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; unfortunately this doesn't match what I see.

I made a simple graph that takes an existing avi file, splits into video/audio streams, and then shifts the timestamps and the audio forward by about 100 ms. Then this is combined back via AVI mux and written out. The result is an AVI file that is smaller and 6 frames shorter. I can repeat the process and continually trim 6 frames off each time. All video frames have positive timestamps.

I did not realize negative timestamps could also lead to dropping, so I will be on the lookout for that.

Comment: To add a bit and clarify after more experiments, shifting the audio forward results in an AVI file that is the same size as the original, but looking at the resulting AVI file in directshow, virtualdub, etc, all the frames before the first audio frame are skipped. If you run the resulting file through a simple avi splitter and avi mux back, that is when the file size will actually drop.

Comment: I also confirmed your statement about negative timestamps; if an entire video sample's time is negative, it is indeed dropped. If any part is positive, it is retained. The directshow source I am working with does indeed sometimes spit out the first frame with time entirely negative, so this is great to know and saves me other headaches.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr - For my use case, a frame I process not being present in the final AVI is showstopper, and the AVI mux/demux process is complicated enough that I'm better off just assuming some small number of frames may be dropped at the beginning. So I'll likely settle on pushing a number of special frames at the beginning (identified with a GUID/counter pair encoded in the pixels) before I start processing frames. I can then look for these special frames after writing the AVI to identify the frame where processing begins is present.**

Everything I've seen leads me to believe what I originally asked for is effectively not possible. Based on file size, I think technically the video frames are written to the AVI file, but for most intents, they might as well not be.

That is, avi players like virtualdub and VLC, and even the directshow AVI splitter, ignore/drop any video frames present before the audio starts. So I imagine you'd have to parse the AVI file with some other library to extract the pre-audio frames.

The reason I care about this is because I write a parallel data structure with an entry for each frame in the AVI file, and I need to know which data goes with which frame. If frames are dropped from the AVI, I can't match the frames and the data.

I had success with creating custom transform filters after the video/audio capture filters. These filters look at the timestamps and drop the video frames until an audio start time is established and the video frames are after that time. Then the filters downstream know that they can rely on the video frames they process being written. The drawback is that the audio filter actually delivers samples a bit delayed, so when audio starts at 100ms, I don't find out until I'm already handling the video frame at 250ms, meaning I've dropped 250ms of video data to ensure I know when video frames will have accompanying audio. Combine that with different AVI tools behaving differently when video starts more than 1 video sample duration after the audio starts, and my confidence in trying to control the AVIMux/Splitter starts to wane.

All of that leads me to just accept that the AVIMux and AVI Splitter are complicated enough to not make it worth trying to control them exactly.